# Is there a way to specify VCToolsVersion in CMake command line arguments or conanfile.py?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, conan

I'm trying to create a conan package of some company code. The code resides in the gitlab repo and I can't modify it. I want to specify the `VCToolsVersion` for my conan package. The easiest way would be to put `CMakeSettings.json` file in the repo and put these lines in it.

```
"environments": [
  {
      "VCToolsVersion": "14.24"
  }
  ]
```

But since I cannot modify the repo I have to give the `VCToolsVersion` in my `conanfile.py`. I have the following build method in the `conanfile.py`.

```
def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()
```

Is there a way I can specify the `VCToolsVersion` in the arguments of `configure()` method?

```
cmake.configure(args="-Dvcvars_ver=14.24")
```

Comment: Do you mean toolset version? The CMake build helper accepts toolset version on its constructor: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html#constructor

Comment: @uilianries Thanks, I found what I was doing wrong in `toolset` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @uilianries, I found how to specify the MSVC version.

```
def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self, toolset="v142,version=14.24")
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()
```